# Can I say "people weren't singing" even if people didn't exist?

Tags: subjects

I heard something from the room, but I entered the room, just birds were singing.

In this case, can I say "people weren't singing" even though people didn't exist?

> Does "people weren't singing" imply the existence of people?
>
> **ChatGPT**
> Yes, the phrase "people weren't singing" implies the existence of people, as it references their absence or lack of engagement in singing.

I searched from GPT, but it said "people weren't singing" implies the existence of people. But in my language, "people weren't singing" is possible even if people didn't exist.

Comment: Can you say ***Unicorns don't exist*** in your language? Or ***Dinosaurs aren't roaming the Earth today***? These are normal constructions in English. You must be trying to make some inappropriate translation, I think. You shouldn't waste your time asking chatgpt about things like this, though. It has a strong tendency to agree with whatever you "think" might be true (which it will often infer by the way you phrase your question).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a bit philosophical, but why does "the king of France isn't ruling the France" not have truth-value? Does it imply the existence of the king of France?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't have truth-value". The statement is "nonsensical" because syntactically speaking, "**the** king of France" refers to a specific person. But no such person exists. The statement ***A** king of France isn't ruling the country* is syntactically valid (it's still not true, and it's a daft thing to say, but at least it's not inherently invalid).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sorry but why is it not true? There's no king in France, so is it true that a king of France isn't ruling France?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking us to proofread an AI bot.

Comment: People weren't singing, birds were. But this is not a question **about English**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the chat bot output was the OP's prior research, not really part of the question itself. (I don't personally think that's a good way to research, but the question includes a real question and the asker's explanation.)

Comment: Or "There were no people singing, only birds".

Comment: This is the kind of ambiguity in the English language that is used for humor by writers like Douglas Adams: "The spaceships hung in the sky in much the same way that bricks don't". Logically, there's no strict implication that the people exist in your example, but in practice you wouldn't say "people weren't singing" unless there were people there about which one might ask whether they were singing, so the people are implied by the context in which you would reasonably utter the expression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can I say "ice is melted" even though there's no ice and there's only melted ice which is water?

Comment: @ThePhoton or more directly Lewis Carroll "No birds were flying overhead // There were no birds to fly."  Here the exact point made by the OP is used for a joke.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't say "Ice is melted",  but they would say "**The** ice **has** melted" if the water from the melted ice is still present. If there's no longer even any *water* left (it soaked or evaporated away), we probably wouldn't use Present Perfect ***has** melted*, but we might say *"**The ice melted**"* (when there's no *current* sign of either ice or water).

Comment: "ice is melted" even though there's no ice [NOW] and there's only melted ice which is [NOW] water? **But in the beginning there was ice**. 1. Birds singing in a room is highly unlikely. You normally hear birds singing outside, in the trees somewhere. 2. People sing songs and songs have words. Birds cannot imitate people singing songs with lyrics. **People sing or hum, birds chirp or tweet**. The question is not about English language but about logic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the English language but semantics and logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the context you've provided, "People weren't singing" is not idiomatic. It is a grammatical utterance, true, but its meaning, *in the circumstances you have sketched out*, is indeterminate. The meaning of an utterance is *contextual*.

The core problem in your context is that you're thinking to yourself and talking to yourself.

One could express the fact idiomatically in a number of ways. Here's one:

> It wasn't people singing after all. It was birds.

Comment: "*People* weren't singing -- *birds* were." I don't think there's necessarily anything un-idiomatic about OP's phrasing if it were to be used in this context.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck But that's not what OP said.  I would accept your version but it would require intonation, just as you have indicated.

Answer (score 4):

This is contextually dependent. You can't tell from the statement alone if there were any people present.

For example, Lewis Carroll plays with this in his poem when he writes

> No birds were flying overhead —
>   There were no birds to fly.

English has a system of articles that can help.  If you say "The people weren't singing." Then you expect your listener to know which people you are talking about.

It doesn't mean that the people still existed at the time you speak (they could be dead, for example). And it is natural to say "The ice melted", even though it isn't ice after it has melted.

Context is critical. What would are you trying to communicate?  You don't just say "People weren't singing" without any context.  It must be part of a narrative or a description.

Carrol's poem works as a joke because it plays with our expectations.  We expect the second line to explain why the birds weren't flying (has something stopped the birds from flying? It seems sinister) but then Carroll gives the most trivial of reasons.

Comment: "Yesterday, upon the stair // I met a man who wasn't there // He wasn't there again today // I wish that man would go away!"